# Evaluating integrals of periodic functions

Tags: calculus, soft-question, fourier-analysis

I have a question that I think may be hard, so I am trying to understand it more generally.

Say $f$ is a smooth function on the unit circle, so it is a $2\pi$ periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$. I am concerned with integrals of the form
$$r\int_0^\pi f(\theta)\sin\theta d\theta,$$
where $r$ is some positive constant (the circle's radius). This can be thought of as in some sense scaling the contributions of the infinitesimal elements of the circumference in polar coordinates.

Now, my issue is that I am getting somewhat complicated expressions for $f$, and there seems to be no way to evaluate the integral. It occurred to me, however, that Fourier analysis or convolution might be able to help, or that wise people might have solved this problem generally.

My question is: am I right about suspecting a general theory or some kind of clever techniques? If so, what are they? If not, are there any tools I can use to help with problems of this sort?

Comment: Without knowing more about $f$ it's pretty hard to say anything meaningful.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I can say some things about $f$, but they are likely to be specific to the problem, and then when I want to solve a different one $f$ will change.

Comment: With some work (on extending $f$ to $[\pi,2\pi]$ with the right symmetry) you could change the integral to the first Fourier coefficient. However this will not help you much, as the way to calculate this coefficient is to solve the integral. The form also suggest a way to reinterpret this into an integral over the two dimensional sphere, but I assume that is where you came from...

Comment: That is correct, I am integrating over moving 2-spheres, $f$ captures the intersection of the points of the sphere with some other moving surface.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate it analytically or numerically?

Comment: Analytically...

Comment: Perhaps $f(\theta)\sin\theta$ is simpler than $f(\theta)$?

Comment: In one case I have found this is true, and the integral is easy.